# Excel Shows Multiple Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**The value from each cells Range I12:AM12.**
[image: Cell Value]

```
=SUM(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($BE$10,I12:AM12)),VALUE(LEFT(I12:AM12,FIND($BE$10,I12:AM12)-1)),0)>=8,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($BE$10,I12:AM12)),VALUE(LEFT(I12:AM12,FIND($BE$10,I12:AM12)-1)),0),0))-(BE12*8)
```

**This excel formula should show output of 6.0 as per below.**

[image: Output]

**However, when trying to change the formula, or edit. The value will change to -24.0. Even not edit it yet, just press enter on the formula itself will make it return different value than what it supposed.**

[image: Unwanted Output]

Need your guys help with this.

I've tried various solutions, generate new formula, even using . The problem is still unsolved.

The formula supposed to find value with "P" in the range cells which is more or equal to 8 and minus with 8. Then, do the addition of the total sum after minus.

In this case the value shoud retun 6.0.

Example: Cells Range I12:AM12 contains various value some of it have contains letter "P" and the cell value that contains "P" is the only value that needed to be count, apart from other values. The "P" letters is use to flag the value only.

The formula seems to be correct, however, after I'm about to change the value from 8 to 7.5 the output will be change to -24.0 instead of correct value. And, I will never get the output of 6.0 again, even if I change it back to 8.

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand what the formula should return - may you can edit the para where you describe what the formula is supposed to do.

Comment: I edit to put an example already.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand "Then, times with total "P" found."

Comment: My mistake, I'll ammend it, The formula should do this.
11P-8=3, 10P-8=2, 9P-8=1 then 3+2+1=6 it shoud return 6 in the cells.

Comment: Question: in your formula your are referencing BE12 - why? and is this a formula as well?

Comment: Did you try formula auditing? Ribbon "Formulas", choose "Formula Auditing", "Evaluate Formula". There you can "Step in", performing every step of your formula and see when it goes wrong. (Tip: try to predict what the outcome will be and in case of different, you might have found the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will do the trick:

```
=LET(
    data,I12:AM12,
    subset,FILTER(data,NOT(ISERROR(FIND("P",data)))),
    num,VALUE(LEFT(subset,LEN(subset)-2)),
    SUM(num-8)
)
```

This solution requires the Office365 version of Excel.

Note, with the expression `LEN(subset)-2` within the formula, it assumes that the number is always seperated from the "P" by one character, e.g. a space. That means, the formula only works this way if values featuring a "P" appear in the form "5 P" or "11 P", but not in the form "11P".

---

For earlier versions of excel where the functions `LET()` and `FILTER()` are not available, the formula here below can be used instead

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND("P",I12:AM12)^0*VALUE(LEFT(I12:AM12,2))-8,0))
```

This is still an array formula and has to be entered with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I'm using Excel H&B 2019

Comment: Ok, no problem. The `LET()` function is not needed and the `FILTER()` can be dodged with an `INDEX()` function. I'll rewrite it later

Comment: Just edited the post by adding an alternative formula. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It workings. The issue is that, I don't enter the array formula with the key combination. What a silly me. Thanks again for helping. :D